# AES/CFB8 cipher on iOS

Tags: ios, encryption, aes, commoncrypto

I am trying to implement an AES/CFB8 streaming cipher on iOS. I believe that the way to accomplish this is to use the CommonCrypto library provided by Apple.

All of the little documentation I have found only shows block ciphers, so how would one use the library to accomplish an AES/CFB8 stream cipher?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can take a look at the code to encrypt/decrypt here:
http://robnapier.net/blog/aes-commoncrypto-564

Secondly, I believe that iOS CommonCrypto uses CBC by default and the only other option is to use [`kCCOptionECBMode` flag](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-36064/CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h) to get ECB.

If you are fine with CBC, you can use CommonCrypto. If you need specifically CFB than you may need to integrate some 3rd party encryption library.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but, sadly, I have to follow a spec (not my own) calling for CFB8.

Comment: BTW. You can build CFB on your own based on ECB. Look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher_feedback_.28CFB.29